# Шаблон с разнородным содержимым

Tags: django

Пробую по одному из многочисленных примеров делать блог при помощи фреймворка django. Насколько я понимаю (возможно неверно) конечный вид страницы определяется в шаблоне. Вот шаблон, который я использую

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>CP Blog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div>
      <p>published: {{ post.pub_date }}</p>
      <h1><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
      <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Вопрос состоит в следующем: Пост любого блога может содержать совершенно разные элементы страницы. Это могут быть текст, таблицы, рисунки и т.д. и т.п. Причём разные посты могут содержать разное количество тех или иных элементов. В примере же реализован только текст. При попытке использования html тегов непосредственно в теле поста их рендер не происходит. Добавление в шаблон тегов элементов которые в конечном посте могут и не существовать наверное неверно. Читал про создание таблиц в одном из примеров, но их реализация закладывается аж на уровне моделей. Опять же у меня уже есть модель поста, может быть её каким то образом нужно дополнить?

Модель:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.pub_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
#Сreate your models here.
```

Представление:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('pub_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Админка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечный результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `{{ post.text|linebreaksbr|safe }}`

Comment: @andreymal, так, и это позволит отображать произвольный html код?

Comment: Да. . . . . . .

Comment: Почему-то не работает

Comment: Код модели, код вьюхи, скриншот в админке (или где там заполняется post.text) и готовый отрендеренный html-код в студию

Comment: А, у linebreaksbr стоит экранирование, оказывается. Попробуйте наоборот `{{ post.text|safe|linebreaksbr }}`

Comment: Благодарю, завелась ). Оформите как ответ, я отмечу